# create loop/function to add missing rows to dataframe and fill with 0s

Tags: r, loops, na

I have summarized a data frame and would like to add missing years and fill in these missing rows w/ 0s, where appropriate. Here is my start data:

```
start_data <- structure(list(park = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("apis", 
"grpo", "isro", "miss", "piro", "sacn", "slbe", "voya"), class = "factor"), 
    loc_01 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("apis", 
    "isro", "miss", "non_apis", "non_grpo", "non_isro", "non_miss", 
    "non_piro", "non_sacn", "non_slbe", "non_voya", "piro", "sacn", 
    "slbe", "voya"), class = "factor"), year = c(2005L, 2006L, 
    2007L, 2008L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2003L, 
    2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L
    ), agriculture = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2.83549420428, 0, 26.41126099384, 
    9.07370206906, 11.00043405833, 1.440345049, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), beaver = c(0, 0.29706355242, 1.25997210478, 
    1.5123175298, 9.14483092902, 0.70214089206, 2.78157443836, 
    4.42825988163, 0.9900762968, 2.3401234612, 2.8808849429, 
    1.2604019414, 0.54011663526, 0.729245712, 5.45502002852, 
    2.7912116718, 3.0604650244, 1.51253347654, 0.9002514858, 
    2.7548091776), blowdown = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.23207970694, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.81011784036, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), .Names = c("park", "loc_01", "year", "agriculture", "beaver", 
"blowdown"))
```

And it looks like this:

```
   park   loc_01 year agriculture    beaver  blowdown
1  apis     apis 2005    0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2  apis     apis 2006    0.000000 0.2970636 0.0000000
3  apis     apis 2007    0.000000 1.2599721 0.0000000
4  apis     apis 2008    0.000000 1.5123175 0.0000000
5  apis non_apis 2004    2.835494 9.1448309 0.0000000
6  apis non_apis 2005    0.000000 0.7021409 0.0000000
7  apis non_apis 2006   26.411261 2.7815744 2.2320797
8  apis non_apis 2007    9.073702 4.4282599 0.0000000
9  apis non_apis 2008   11.000434 0.9900763 0.0000000
10 apis non_apis 2009    1.440345 2.3401235 0.0000000
11 isro     isro 2003    0.000000 2.8808849 0.0000000
12 isro     isro 2005    0.000000 1.2604019 0.0000000
13 isro     isro 2006    0.000000 0.5401166 0.0000000
14 isro     isro 2007    0.000000 0.7292457 0.8101178
15 isro non_isro 2003    0.000000 5.4550200 0.0000000
16 isro non_isro 2004    0.000000 2.7912117 0.0000000
17 isro non_isro 2005    0.000000 3.0604650 0.0000000
18 isro non_isro 2006    0.000000 1.5125335 0.0000000
19 isro non_isro 2007    0.000000 0.9002515 0.0000000
20 isro non_isro 2008    0.000000 2.7548092 0.0000000
```

I would like to add rows in for missing years, based upon the park id. For example, where `park == apis`, years 2005:2009 should be present, both for `apis` and `non_apis`. Here I could reference a list, like `apis.yrs <- 2004:2009`. Where `park == isro`, years 2003:2008 should be present, again, both for `isro` and `non_isro`. Again, another list could be created for the years, `isro.yrs <- 2003:2008`. When these new rows are added, `agriculture`, `beaver`, and `blowdown` should all be filled 0s.

This is my end goal:

```
goal <- structure(list(park = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("", "apis", "isro"), class = "factor"), loc_01 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("apis", "isro", "miss", 
"non_apis", "non_isro", "non_miss", "non_piro", "non_sacn", "non_slbe", 
"non_voya", "piro", "sacn", "slbe", "voya"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2004L, 
    2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
    2007L, 2008L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L), 
    agriculture = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.835494204, 0, 26.41126099, 
    9.073702069, 11.00043406, 1.440345049, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), beaver = c(0, 0, 0.297063552, 1.259972105, 
    1.51231753, 0, 9.144830929, 0.702140892, 2.781574438, 4.428259882, 
    0.990076297, 2.340123461, 2.880884943, 0, 1.260401941, 0.540116635, 
    0.729245712, 0, 5.455020029, 2.791211672, 3.060465024, 1.512533477, 
    0.900251486, 2.754809178), blowdown = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 2.232079707, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.81011784, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), .Names = c("park", "loc_01", "year", "agriculture", "beaver", 
"blowdown"))
```

And looks like this....

```
   park   loc_01 year agriculture    beaver  blowdown
1  apis     apis 2004    0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2  apis     apis 2005    0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
3  apis     apis 2006    0.000000 0.2970636 0.0000000
4  apis     apis 2007    0.000000 1.2599721 0.0000000
5  apis     apis 2008    0.000000 1.5123175 0.0000000
6  apis     apis 2009    0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
7  apis non_apis 2004    2.835494 9.1448309 0.0000000
8  apis non_apis 2005    0.000000 0.7021409 0.0000000
9  apis non_apis 2006   26.411261 2.7815744 2.2320797
10 apis non_apis 2007    9.073702 4.4282599 0.0000000
11 apis non_apis 2008   11.000434 0.9900763 0.0000000
12 apis non_apis 2009    1.440345 2.3401235 0.0000000
13 isro     isro 2003    0.000000 2.8808849 0.0000000
14 isro     isro 2004    0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
15 isro     isro 2005    0.000000 1.2604019 0.0000000
16 isro     isro 2006    0.000000 0.5401166 0.0000000
17 isro     isro 2007    0.000000 0.7292457 0.8101178
18 isro     isro 2008    0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
19 isro non_isro 2003    0.000000 5.4550200 0.0000000
20 isro non_isro 2004    0.000000 2.7912117 0.0000000
21 isro non_isro 2005    0.000000 3.0604650 0.0000000
22 isro non_isro 2006    0.000000 1.5125335 0.0000000
23 isro non_isro 2007    0.000000 0.9002515 0.0000000
24 isro non_isro 2008    0.000000 2.7548092 0.0000000
```

Where years 2004, 2009 were added where `loc_01==apis` and years 2004, 2008 added where `loc_01==isro`.

-al

Comment: Do you have actual `NA` values in your existing dataset?

Comment: There are no actual `NA` values in my existing dataset. The answer provided by @Ananda worked flawlessly. A nice succinct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expand.grid` + `merge` is useful for these kinds of problems.

You can try something like this:

Step 1: Create a `data.frame` with all the combinations you want to have included.

```
toMerge <- rbind(
  expand.grid(park = "apis", 
              loc_01 = c("apis", "non_apis"), 
              year = 2004:2009),
  expand.grid(park = "isro",
              loc_01 = c("isro", "non_isro"),
              year = 2003:2008)
)
```

Step 2: `merge` with your original `data.frame`.

```
merge(start_data, toMerge, all = TRUE)
#    park   loc_01 year agriculture    beaver  blowdown
# 1  apis     apis 2004          NA        NA        NA
# 2  apis     apis 2005    0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
# 3  apis     apis 2006    0.000000 0.2970636 0.0000000
# 4  apis     apis 2007    0.000000 1.2599721 0.0000000
# 5  apis     apis 2008    0.000000 1.5123175 0.0000000
# 6  apis     apis 2009          NA        NA        NA
# 7  apis non_apis 2004    2.835494 9.1448309 0.0000000
# 8  apis non_apis 2005    0.000000 0.7021409 0.0000000
# 9  apis non_apis 2006   26.411261 2.7815744 2.2320797
# 10 apis non_apis 2007    9.073702 4.4282599 0.0000000
# 11 apis non_apis 2008   11.000434 0.9900763 0.0000000
# 12 apis non_apis 2009    1.440345 2.3401235 0.0000000
# 13 isro     isro 2003    0.000000 2.8808849 0.0000000
# 14 isro     isro 2004          NA        NA        NA
# 15 isro     isro 2005    0.000000 1.2604019 0.0000000
# 16 isro     isro 2006    0.000000 0.5401166 0.0000000
# 17 isro     isro 2007    0.000000 0.7292457 0.8101178
# 18 isro     isro 2008          NA        NA        NA
# 19 isro non_isro 2003    0.000000 5.4550200 0.0000000
# 20 isro non_isro 2004    0.000000 2.7912117 0.0000000
# 21 isro non_isro 2005    0.000000 3.0604650 0.0000000
# 22 isro non_isro 2006    0.000000 1.5125335 0.0000000
# 23 isro non_isro 2007    0.000000 0.9002515 0.0000000
# 24 isro non_isro 2008    0.000000 2.7548092 0.0000000
```

From there, it's not difficult to replace the `NA` with 0.